# How to set a script to run without password in sudoers whose path may change

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sudo, sudoers

I have an environmental variable that changes when installing our software.
Lets say this environmental variable is `$SOFTWARE_ROOT`.

This script is located in

```
$SOFTWARE_ROOT/run_script
```

How can I set something like $SOFTWARE_ROOT/run_script as NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers?

Answer (score 0):

Given that $SOFTWARE_ROOT can be changed by the end user, specifying the variable in a sudoers configuration file would be completely meaningless.

Just allow sudoers access for `run_script` regardless of path, or allow access to every path where you know `run_script` can possibly ever exist.